How to build project with AWS CodeBuild using different Personal Access Tokens from Github?
I am building my own app deployment platform where users can create a project by connecting to Github and then they can choose which repo they want to build and host using my platform. You can compare it with Vercel or Railway.
I want to use AWS under the hood to manage deployments and hosting.
So I read the docs for AWS CodeBuild SDK
And I thought that was exactly what I needed to build the projects of my customers.
But I came to a problem.
I don't think you can create a CodeBuild project using github personal access tokens.
You can only do it by connecting your account via oauth in amazon console.
This is the code that I tried:
export async function buildProject(projectName: string, mainBranch: string) {
  const session = await auth();
  if (!session) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    const githubAccessToken = session.user?.accessToken;

    console.log(`https://${githubAccessToken}@github.com/${projectName}`);

    const codebuild = new CodeBuildClient({
      region: "us-west-1",
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID!,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
      },
    });

    const params: CreateProjectInput = {
      // Create a unique project name
      serviceRole: "arn:aws:iam::051950967555:role/codebuild-dev",
      name: uuidv4(),
      sourceVersion: mainBranch,
      source: {
        type: "GITHUB",
        location: `https://github.com/${projectName}`,
        auth: {
          type: "PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN", // Type '"PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"' is not assignable to type 'SourceAuthType | undefined'.
          resource: githubAccessToken,
        },
      },

      artifacts: {
        type: "NO_ARTIFACTS",
      },
      environment: {
        computeType: "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL",
        type: "LINUX_CONTAINER",
        image: "aws/codebuild/standard:4.0",
      },
    };

    const project = await codebuild.send(new CreateProjectCommand(params));

    return project;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
}

So now I am wondering if i am even using the right service for this.
Should I use codebuild if I want to reploy apps for hundreds of user? or should I use codepipeline?
My original idea whas to do it via codebuild, install buildpacks and use it to generate a docker image and then host it on ECS
Thanks you in advance
I tried using using codebuild because I thought it was a good option for building all user repos, but maybe I need to use codepipeline or even provision my own EC2 instances? for building the source code

CodeBuild supports Personal access token. You can import PAT token using console or API.

API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeBuild.html#importSourceCredentials-property

Once the PAT token is imported, you can go ahead and create a new project. You should not need to include the auth object in the input - codebuild will use the PAT token you've previously imported
const params: CreateProjectInput = {
      // Create a unique project name
      serviceRole: "arn:aws:iam::051950967555:role/codebuild-dev",
      name: uuidv4(),
      sourceVersion: mainBranch,
      source: {
        type: "GITHUB",
        location: `https://github.com/${projectName}`
      },

      artifacts: {
        type: "NO_ARTIFACTS",
      },
      environment: {
        computeType: "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL",
        type: "LINUX_CONTAINER",
        image: "aws/codebuild/standard:4.0",
      },
    };

